# While testing api in postman getting error 404

Tags: spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

## Model Class

```
public class SimpleResponse {

    private String message;
    private long id;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

## Controller class

```
@RestController
public class WebController {

    // @RequestParam indicates that the endpoint /sample will have one Query
    // parameter called name.
    @RequestMapping("/sample")
    public SimpleResponse sample(@RequestParam(value = "name", defaultValue = "Kabir") String name) {
        SimpleResponse sm = new SimpleResponse();
        sm.setId(1);
        sm.setMessage("This message is for Kabir"+name);
        return sm;
    }
}
```

[image]
While developing a Spring Boot Rest Api i am geeting 404 error.Unable to find the Error.Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: can you check your application.properties if any property like server.contextPath?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting "No message available" error with Spring Boot + REST application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135205/getting-no-message-available-error-with-spring-boot-rest-application)

Answer (score 0):

Above code works fine, did you check your application logs?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check whether if your `application.properties` file contains a property as `server.servlet.context-path`. If it does, then append that to your URL after the domain.

```
http://localhost:8888/<append_here>/sample?name=Kabir
```