# Error 500 using EntityManager in PostRequest

Tags: java, spring-boot, post, entitymanager

FINAL EDIT: Sorry I'm sure this post is very hard to follow, I'm updating it for future posterity. I never figured out what is the issue with my `@PersistenceContext` annotation, I ended up giving up and just moved on to using a CrudRepository instead.

our repository interface that implements from CrudRepository:

```
public interface RepositoryCar extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {
}
```

Make a service Interface (not necessary but it's better practice):

```
public interface ServiceInterface {
    Car addCar(Car car);
    Car findCar(long carId);
}
```

make the implementing subclass @Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class ServiceCar implements ServiceInterface{
    //autowire this so it can instantiate your CrudRepository class.
    @Autowired
    RepositoryCar repositoryCar;


    public Car addCar(Car car) {
        return repositoryCar.save(car);
    }

    public Car findCar(long carId) {
        Optional<Car> present=repositoryCar.findById(carId);
        if(present.isPresent())
        {
            return present.get();
        }
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

So that's my cluster of a post, I'm still curious as to why my `@PersistenceContext` wasn't picked up on somehow, but all my endpoints were setup correctly, I would still love to hear an explanation. I just moved on and used a CrudRepository though, there are multiple ways to do this.

Original post below:

I am trying to make a PostRequest and store information about my Car object using Spring Boot. I was following a guide where I have done this previously and it worked, so I'm trying to refollow that guide and my prior example, but I seem to be missing something. I get a generic error 500, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

my Car class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cars")
public class Car {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String color;
    private int year;

    public Car(String make, String model, String color, int year) {
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.color = color;
        this.year = year;
    }
    //getters and setters
```

My CarController class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
public class CarsController {
    CarsRepository repository;

    public CarsController(CarsRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Car addCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
        repository.addCar(car);
        return car;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public CarsRepository getCars() {
        return repository;
    }
}
```

My Car Repository:

```
@Repository
public class CarsRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    @Transactional
    public void addCar(Car car) {

        entityManager.persist(car);
    }

    public Car find(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
    }
}
```

My Application.yml:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    generate-ddl: true
    properties.hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/cars?useSSL=false
    username: root
```

In my prior examples that work, I have used this same `application.yml`, and I double checked that I do not have a password set, so I have omitted that field.

I made a database and table. The following SQL code makes the table. Making the table in unnecessary as the table is automatically generated, I dropped the table and just had the database exist at the end of all this:

```
CREATE TABLE car (
  id         BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  make       VARCHAR(20),
  model      VARCHAR(20),
  color      VARCHAR(20),
  year       INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
  ENGINE = innodb
  DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

My main SpringBootApplication class is very straightforward:

```
package study.example;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

I was wondering if my table was set up incorrectly somehow, so I copy pasted my prior working example and it too gave me an error 500, so I do not think my table is incorrect because I'm certain my prior table for a different Application works.

When I do my post request in PostMan, I always get back an error 500, so I changed it from EntityManger to just an in memory HashMap, and it works fine, so I'm certain it's the EntityManager that is the problem.

Is there some component that I'm missing here, or is something I've done wrong? I have spent far too much time on this, but it looks like I'm following my past example identically, but obviously not.

My post request:

```
{
    "make" : "make",
    "model" : "model",
    "color" : "blue",
    "year" : 2000
}
```

and the response is pretty useless, it just says

```
{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-29T03:29:06.110+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/cars/"
}
```

Thank you for any help, it's greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I now realize I am actually getting some useful error message in the logs, as Dmitriy pointed out. I am getting a NullPointer Exception. Here is the entire stacktrace:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at study.example.CarsRepository.addCar(CarsRepository.java:19) ~[main/:na]
        at study.example.CarsController.addCar(CarsController.java:23) ~[main/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:891) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:974) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:877) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:851) ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:685) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.34.jar:8.5.34]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

EDIT: I'm pretty sure it's my build.gradle that is the problem, because I don't see what else it could be. I'm surprised that it even compiles if that's the problem to be honest, but here it is anyways:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = "2.0.6.RELEASE"
        springVersion = "5.0.10.RELEASE"
        hibernateVersion = "5.2.17.Final"
        slf4jVersion = "1.7.25"
        junitVersion = "4.12"
        mysqlVersion = "5.1.40"
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion"

    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:$springBootVersion")
    compile "com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:2.7.0"
    compile("mysql:mysql-connector-java:6.0.6")
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:$hibernateVersion"
    compile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:$slf4jVersion"
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:$springBootVersion")

}

springBoot {
    buildInfo()
}

bootRun.environment([
        "WELCOME_MESSAGE": "hello"
])
```

Comment: What does the log say? Is there an exception? If so: please include the stack trace and highlight the line of code causing the exception. How does the body of your request look like? Does it by any chance violate a database constraint?

Comment: Hope this will be useful: https://github.com/dineshbhagat/spring-boot-web-jpa

Comment: That's the problem, the error code is pretty useless. It just says
```{
    "timestamp": "2019-06-29T03:29:06.110+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/cars/"
}```

I'm going to edit the post with my post request and the response.

Comment: Does your application class have the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation? See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135205/getting-no-message-available-error-with-spring-boot-rest-application)

Comment: Yeah I have an `@SpringBootApplication`. My app runs correctly if I just remove the EntityManager and replace it with a HashMap, so I'm sure that the only problem is the repository, the rest of my app works correctly.

Comment: Please post an exception which fails on server side (most probably in the log of your Spring Boot app). Just a response with 500 / Internal Server Error does not say anything particular about the error.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't realize I was actually getting a real response in the logs! That's why I have was having such a hard time debugging, an error 500 tells me nothing. I'm getting a NullPointerException. I'm omitted the rest of the stack trace because it seems unimportant.

```java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at study.example.CarsRepository.addCar(CarsRepository.java:18) ~[main/:na]
        at study.example.CarsController.addCar(CarsController.java:31) ~[main/:na]
```

Comment: The id is auto-generated, you are not supposed to assign value to it manually.

Comment: Yeah, I think that post request was from when I did it using a HashMap rather than the actual EntityManager. I tried without an explicit ID because I know it's autogeneratd. It seems the issue is the NPE, so I don't imagine getting rid of the ID in the post request will help, though that is a good point and now that I've moved to the EntityManager, I do need to not send an ID explicitly.

Comment: I don't see any annotation on the Repository class. Have you added @Repository?

Comment: SO didn't show it because my backtick syntax for code formatting was slightly wrong, it's there. I edited the post with this, but I'll respond here as well. It seems the issue is I haven't registered my application as an EJB, so it just ignores the @PersistenceContext annotation. 

https://coderanch.com/t/468434/databases/nullPointerException-entity-manager-methods

I'll look into this tomorrow, I just hopped on real quick to see if I had the annotation there. Thanks for everyone's help, I should figure this out tomorrow once I figure out how to register it as an EJB it seems.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` will take care of injecting the `EntityManager` you don't need to register it as an EJB. Basically a field in a Spring based application cannot be `null`. If Spring cannot fulfill autowiring (`@PersistenceContext` included) it will throw an exception at startup. So you are either doing weird things in your configuration/setup or are doing `new CarRepository` in your code yourself.

Comment: @JoshSuttenberg Why are you not using `JpaRepository`?

Comment: @AvijitBarua I'm not using JpaRepository simply because the guide I was following didn't, I've done this the way I am trying to and it worked, I just can't find where the difference is. I am going to look into using that if that'll make things simpler though.

Comment: @M.Deinum I am not explicitly making a `new CarRepository`. My application is very straight forward so I don't see where the issue is. I have my main `@SpringBootApplication` class, my Controller and Repository classes, the Car class itself, my application.yml, and my HomeController which does almost nothing. I still get the NPE when I try to `entityManager.persist(car);`

Comment: You must be doing something weird as the method is called directly on the `CarRepository` whereas I would expect a proxy. And as stated when doing injection a field cannot be `null` otherwise your application simply wouldn't start. So either you aren't showing everything or are doing weird things in your configuration. Please add your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: Sure, I'll add it to the post, but it's just a main method with the annotation, nothing to it.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am almost certain it's my build.gradle that is the issue, though I didn't except that initially because everything compiles. I tried building it from scratch referring to the documentation, but I encounter other issues that way (classNotFoundException in the Bean initialization, but that's all besides the point). I'm updating my original post with my build.gradle

Comment: The problem lies somewhere in your code or configuration (although your `build.gradle` could use some cleaning up). The fact that you get an error is interesting, please ad the full stacktrace. One thing is that your `Car` entity would need a default  constructor. Is it possible you share the actual code you are using?

Comment: I made a default Car constructor because I thought the same thing. My application is honestly very simple, all the code I'm using is in my post. Only thing I have omitted is my HomeController class, but everything else is there. I've gone through a couple of different iterations so my code isn't exactly as my main post (only things that are different are build.gradle and the application.yml, but it should all be equivalent). I dropped my cars table because I read that the EntityManager will make it for me, and worst case I should get a different error and fix it then. I posted the stacktrace

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you so much for your help by the way. I'm sure I'm missing something incredibly obvious/silly, but I can't for the life of me figure this out and it's really been blocking me on continuing my work.

Comment: The thing is that your `@Transactional` isn't applied, I don't see a proxy in your stacktrace. Hence my firm believe that your `CarsRepository` isn't spring managed. If not Spring managed no injection will take place nor will the `@Transactional` be processed. That and only that is the only reason for this error. So you must be doing a `new CarsRepository()` somewhere in your code (do you have an `@Configuration` class somewhre?). Do you have a github or other repository link to your code?

Comment: I can upload it to github. I don't have an `@Configuration` class anywhere, and I'm not making a `new CarsRepository()` anywhere, so I really am baffled what I'm doing wrong where. The other Spring annotations work like my `@GetMapping` and stuff like that, so I'm not sure I understand how my `CarsRepository` isn't spring managed somehow.

Comment: The github repo: https://github.com/JoshSuttenberg/cars-monolith. I was getting an issue committing my .gradle folder, because it gave the following error, so for simplicity I just omitted it. 

error: read error while indexing .gradle/5.4.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.lock: Permission denied
error: .gradle/5.4.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.lock: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file '.gradle/5.4.1/executionHistory/executionHistory.lock'
fatal: adding files failed

Comment: @DmitriyPopov So I gave up with the EntityMangaer and just moved onto a CrudRepository implementation, I edited my main post. Thanks for all your time and help.

Answer (score -1):

In your code for the class `CarsRepository.java`  , you have provided the annotation `@Transactional` on the method .Try using it like below :

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CarsRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager entityManager;

    public void addCar(Car car) {

        entityManager.persist(car);
    }

    public Car find(Long id) {
        return entityManager.find(Car.class, id);
    }
}
```

> @PersistenceContext: A persistence context handles a set of entities
>   which hold data to be persisted in some persistence store (e.g. a
>   database). In particular, the context is aware of the different states
>   an entity can have (e.g. managed, detached) in relation to both the
>   context and the underlying persistence store.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I still get a NPE doing this.

Comment: You can also inject into classes without `@Transactional`... Nothing is preventing that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you for correcting me.I have corrected my answer of that statement.

Comment: @M.Deinum An entity becomes managed with an entity manager with an active transaction right.Then, how can it be injected to a class that is not transactional ? Can you please clarify my doubt

Comment: You don't need an active transaction to make an entity managed. If you actually want to persist it you do. You can also manually manage the transaction, why would you then require a transaction for the simple fact of injecting an `EntityManager`.

Comment: Oh alright, Thanks a lot ,my thought was that an entity gets managed by an entity manager only when a transaction is active..But when you just inject an entity manager without a transaction there is a possibility that the entity manager might not be managing that entity at the time , right ? The entity gets managed by the entity manager only if an action is performed like refresh or persist ?